# Error when adding my npm module to imports

Tags: angular, npm, stackblitz

Any help in understanding why I'm getting this error below installing and then referencing npm Angular2-wizard in my Stackblitz.

I have this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fmkkwx?file=src/test/test.module.ts) and I installed [angular2-wizard](https://github.com/maiyaporn/angular2-wizard). After I installed it I referenced it in my test.module.ts file like this (according to the docs):

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { StripeComponent } from './stripe/stripe.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgxStripeModule } from 'ngx-stripe';
import { FormWizardModule } from 'angular2-wizard';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormWizardModule
  ],
  declarations: [StripeComponent],
  exports: [
    StripeComponent
  ]
})
export class TestModule { }
```

I see this error on the screen:

[image]

Comment: Did you do the bit noted in the development section? https://github.com/maiyaporn/angular2-wizard#development

Comment: How would I do this in my Stackblitz?

Comment: no idea. But I presume you did the stackblitz for question asking purposes and are really working locally. Maybe not true?

Comment: I did the Stackblitz question because I have a bigger problem with this package that I'd like to post on Stackoverflow, but in order to post it, I have to get the damn Angular2-wizard working first. I'm not sure what you mean by "working locally", I guess you mean that I have a project on my machine that is using it?

Comment: the missing files are components of `angular2-wizard`. i think the dependencies are not installed yet, try to restart the server.

Comment: How do I restart the server?

Comment: The error you are getting is likely related to the fact that Angular2-wizard is not compatible with Angular 12 or later. Angular2-wizard was last updated in 2017 and I assume it was designed to work with Angular 2 and Angular 4.

Comment: It works at home with my Angular 15 project.

Answer (score 1):

I have a hunch that this is caused by the the manner in which `angular2-wizard` are exporting these components from their library in `index.ts`:

```
export * from './src/wizard.component';
export * from './src/wizard-step.component';
```

https://github.com/maiyaporn/angular2-wizard/blob/master/index.ts

When Stackblitz initializes it encapsulates/sandboxes the code into a [webcontainer](https://github.com/stackblitz/webcontainer-core) environment. When it tries to resolve the `'./src/wizard.component'` routes it is most likely looking at the root `src` directory that is defined in your project instead of the correct `node_modules/angular2-wizard/src` directory. This may explain why this works for you locally but not here.

I figured that the fix for this would be to rename the `src` directory to something else, however it appears that there may be a bug in Stackblitz for Angular projects because it always tries to reference `/~/src/main.ts` regardless of the name of the directory main.ts is in:

```
Cannot read file '/~/src/main.ts': Error: ENOENT: No such file or directory., '/~/src/main.ts'. The file is in the program because: Root file specified for compilation
```

I am going to raise a bug for this against Stackblitz (will link to this question when I have), but for now it looks like you are out of luck.

https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/2456
https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/2455

Answer (score -1):

### Rather than using `npm` to install angular2-wizard

Try downloading [the source of the latest release](https://github.com/maiyaporn/angular2-wizard/releases/tag/v0.4.0) and copying the files in the `src/` directory (contains the files `wizard.component.ts`, `wizard-step.component.ts`, `wizard.component.spec.ts`, `wizard-step.component.spec.ts`) to your `src/` directory.

Instead of installing angular2-wizard as a package, you're just adding the components to your project.